# Adding Quantity to Cart in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

So I'm not sure whether there are similar questions elsewhere and this is my problem when change or add another qty on same item.

Add item with some qty to cart

[image: For first, i add some items with some qty to my cart]

After inserting item to cart then it will show in my cart list

[image: After inserting item to cart, then the item will show in my cart list. It's look fine]

After that, i add same item but now with different another quantity number (and the problem start...)

[image: Then, i add same item but now with another qty]

The problem now show here in my cart list.
The quatity in my stock is only 5. When i add in first time it's look fine, but when i try to input with another quatity (in this case is 6) it will add to my cart and now my quatity buy is 11. This is over from my stock.

[image: New cart list showing]

This is my controller to add item to cart

```
function addToCart()
{
    $data = array(
        'id'    => @$this->input->post('registerNum'),
        'qty'   => @$this->input->post('buyQty'),
        'price' => @$this->input->post('priceEach'),
        'name'  => @$this->input->post('itemName'),
    );
    $this->cart->insert($data);
    redirect('admin/transaction/add');
}
```

So, anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: Well before adding to cart you need to query the database for quantity of the item, subtract from quantity already in cart and see if value is greater or equal to 0.

Comment: Remove `@` sign. If there are some errors you shouldn't suppress those but solve appropriately. Is there some code in `admin/transaction/add` that could be a reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use code below for validation input qty to cart :

```
function addToCart()
{
    $stock = $this->input->post('stock');
    $qty   = $this->input->post('qty');
    if($qty > $stock){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible"><strong>Sorry!</strong> Quantity more than stock.</div>');
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }

    $data = array(
        'id'    => $this->input->post('registerNum'),
        'stock' => $stock,
        'qty'   => $qty,
        'price' => $this->input->post('priceEach'),
        'name'  => $this->input->post('itemName'),
    );
    $this->cart->insert($data);
    redirect('admin/transaction/add');
}
```